# Disable positive/negative button in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I mimicked what I thought was fairly standard `Dialog` code:

```
public class DChooseSeparator extends DialogFragment
{
    // ...
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        builder
            .setTitle("My Title")
            .setView(myDialogLayout)
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.sOKButton), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    if(myEditText.getText().toString().equals("")) // disable positive button if this is empty
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "enter something!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else { myListener.onSet(myEditText.getText().toString()); }
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.sCancelButton), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

And in `onStart` of the `Fragment` that shows it:

```
sepButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog();
        myDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "tMyDialogTag");
        myDialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);   // DOES NOT WORK
    }
}
```

However, this does not work, as the `getButton` function is not available for my `DialogFragment`. I can also not do this in the `DialogFragment` class, as I need to `show()` it first.

So...where exactly can/should I disable the `Button`? Do I really have to move the whole creation of the `Dialog` to the `onClick` method?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can enable or disable the `Button` after the view of the `FragmentDialog` has been created. So you have to call it in the `onStart()` method of your Dialog.

See my code:

```
public class DChooseSeparator extends DialogFragment
{
    // MEMBER
    private AlertDialog dialog;
    private static boolean mEnableButton;

    // You need an empty constructor: "All subclasses of Fragment must include a public empty constructor. "  
    // like it's described in the Fragment API -> so create a new Insatnce with this static methjod
    public static DChooseSeparator newInstance(boolean enableButton){
        mEnableButton = enableButton;
        return new DChooseSeparator();
    } 
    // ...
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        builder
            .setTitle("My Title")
            .setView(myDialogLayout)
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.sOKButton), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    if(myEditText.getText().toString().equals("")) // disable positive button if this is empty
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "enter something!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else { myListener.onSet(myEditText.getText().toString()); }
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.sCancelButton), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            });

        dialog = builder.create()

        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(mEnableButton);
    }
}
```

Now you can call your Dialog like this:

```
sepButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog(false);
        myDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "tMyDialogTag");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you detailed answer and for taking the time to work that in the example! That did indeed work (though I thought I had tried this as well). I wonder...is this the recommended approach or are you supposed to create the code for the `Dialog` directly in the `Fragment`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to call this after the view of the dialog has been created, in the oncreateview  function of the dialogfragment class

Comment: But then where do I put the show()? I had it in the `Fragment` that created the `Dialog` but now this doesn't work anymore if I want to do stuff in `onCreateView`.

Comment: keep it where it is, add a function to ur MyDialog class setOkEnabled(bool val), and then store this flag value somewhere and then override the oncreateview, if the flag is false disable the ok button

Comment: Alright, I have done what you suggested and added that function and called that after `myDialog.show(...)`. However, this does not work either as the app crashes ass soon as I call it.